# Deserializing SOAP message to C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, soap

So I'm trying to parse SOAP message and i have found many solutions, but in my case additional is giving me an issue.

This is the message I'm trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <getOrderInfoResponse xmlns="http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com">
    <getOrderInfoReturn>
    <additionalDocument>NA</additionalDocument>
    <certificateQty>0</certificateQty>    
    <counterPaidAmount>0.00</counterPaidAmount>
    <countryCode>USA</countryCode>
    <currencyCode>HKD</currencyCode>
    <deliveryCharge>124.20</deliveryCharge>
    <errMessage>Success</errMessage>
    <insurAmount>5000.00</insurAmount>
    <insurPermFee>11.00</insurPermFee>
    <invoiceQty>0</invoiceQty>
    <itemCategory>G</itemCategory>
    <itemNo>JJ059363521HK</itemNo>
    <orderNo>P000000001159994</orderNo>
    <orderStatus>0</orderStatus>
    <products>
      <products>
        <contentDesc>Toy</contentDesc>
        <currencyCode>HKD</currencyCode>
        <productCountry>China, Mainland</productCountry> 
        <productQty>2</productQty>
        <productTariffCode>94</productTariffCode> 
        <productValue>10.000</productValue>
        <productWeight>0.800</productWeight>
      </products>
      <products>
        <contentDesc>Toy</contentDesc>
        <currencyCode>HKD</currencyCode>
        <productCountry>China, Mainland</productCountry> 
        <productQty>3</productQty>
        <productTariffCode>94</productTariffCode> 
        <productValue>15.000</productValue>
        <productWeight>1.000</productWeight>
      </products>
    </products>
    <recipientAddress>Test Receipent Address</recipientAddress>
    <recipientCity>New York</recipientCity> 
    <recipientContactNo>21234567</recipientContactNo> 
    <recipientCountry>USA</recipientCountry>
    <recipientEmail>test-receipent@ec-ship.test</recipientEmail> 
    <recipientFax>22222222</recipientFax>
    <recipientName>Test Receipent</recipientName> 
    <recipientPostalNo>10111</recipientPostalNo>
    <referenceNo>ECShipApi E-Express testing</referenceNo> 
    <satchelAmount>0.00</satchelAmount>
    <satchelTypeCode></satchelTypeCode>
    <senderAddress>Flat T, Testing Block, Testing Buliding, Testing 
     District</senderAddress>
    <senderContactNo>22222222</senderContactNo>
    <senderCountry>Hong Kong SAR</senderCountry>
    <senderEmail>test-sender@ec-ship.test</senderEmail>            
    <senderFax>22222222</senderFax>
    <senderName>Peter Chan</senderName>
    <senderPostalNo></senderPostalNo>
    <shipCode>AEP</shipCode>
    <status>0</status>
    <totWeight>1.800</totWeight>
    <userId>timelhk</userId>
    <webPaidAmount>0.00</webPaidAmount>
    </getOrderInfoReturn>
  </getOrderInfoResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my code:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class SOAPEnvelope
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = 
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public string soapenv { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public string xsd { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string xsi { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = 
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public ResponseBody<GetOrderInfoResponse> body { get; set; }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();


    public SOAPEnvelope()
    {
        xmlns.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = 
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class ResponseBody<T>
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "getOrderInfoResponse", Namespace = 
    "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
    public T getOrderInfoResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "getOrderInfoResponse", Namespace = 
"http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
public class GetOrderInfoResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "getOrderInfoReturn", Namespace = "")]
    public GetOrderInfoModel getOrderInfoReturn { get; set; }
}

var rawXML = XDocument.Parse(result);
        SOAPEnvelope deserializedObject;
        using (var reader = 
rawXML.CreateReader(System.Xml.Linq.ReaderOptions.None))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SOAPEnvelope));
            deserializedObject = (SOAPEnvelope)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        List<GetOrderInfoModel> models = new List<GetOrderInfoModel>();

models.Add(deserializedObject.body.getOrderInfoResponse.getOrderInfoReturn);

return View(models);
```

I have found many solutions like this, but the only difference is that after the body element is the object that needs to be converted to C# object. That kind of examples worked.

In my case "reader" is always "none" and the return value is always null.

I hope that I have provided you with enough of useful information, if not please ask if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your classes.  See code below which works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(result);

            SOAPEnvelope deserializedObject;
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader))
            {

                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SOAPEnvelope));
                deserializedObject = (SOAPEnvelope)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }


        }
    }
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class SOAPEnvelope
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string soapenv { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
        public string xsd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string xsi { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public ResponseBody<GetOrderInfoResponse> body { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class ResponseBody<T>
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getOrderInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
        public T getOrderInfoResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "getOrderInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
    public class GetOrderInfoResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getOrderInfoReturn", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")] 
        public GetOrderInfoReturn  getOrderInfoReturn { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "getOrderInfoResponse", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
    public class GetOrderInfoReturn
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "additionalDocument", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
        public string additionalDocument { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "certificateQty", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
        public int certificateQty { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "deliveryCharge", Namespace = "http://webservice.integrator.hkpost.com")]
        public decimal deliveryCharge { get; set; }
    }

}
```